# How to generate closed-form stiff matrix of triangular prism element by mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

We can generate closed-form stiff matrix of tetrahedron by mathematica:
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3233/

Can we also generate closed-form stiff matrix of triangular prism element by mathematica?

Thanks,
Tang Laoya

Comment: You're going to need to ask a more specific question if you hope to get an answer.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your kindly reply. I need to:
1) create an interpolation function in triangular prism just like V=a+b*x+c*y+d*z for tetrahedron (4 vertices and 4 unknowns);
2) create the shape functions (for tetrahedron it is the volume coordinate but I don't know how to express them for triangular prism);
3) calculate the stiffness matrix, for example, the term
Int(d^2 N/dx^2+d^2 N/dy^2+d^2 N/dz^2) dxdydz, where N is the shape functions
4) give the closed-form express by mathematica.

Thanks

Comment: Do not put revisions, additions to your question in a comment -- make an edit to original question.

Comment: Mathematica has lots of built-in shapes. Type `PolyhedronData[]` and you will see a list. Display the shapes like this: `Graphics3D[{PolyhedronData["TriaugmentedTriangularPrism", "Faces"]}]`. Look at the help file for `PolyhedronData` to see how to get the coordinates of the shape you want.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your kindly reply. I have posted a new question here: 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41979/is-it-possible-to-give-the-closed-form-of-the-stiffness-matrix-of-triangular-pri

could you please help me to take a look at it?

Comment: In the future, please use the "edit" button to modify your existing question if you want to add details.

Comment: OK, thanks Rahul Narain for your kindly remind.